# What's wrong with this code to determine if two lines segments intersect?

Tags: c++, math, line, intersection, algebra

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to return true if the segments cross.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
bool doCross(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4)
{
    bool cross = true;
    double denom, uA, uB;

    denom = (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1);

    if(denom == 0)
    {
        cross = false;
    }
    else
    {
        uA = (x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3) / denom;
        uB = (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3) / denom;
    }
    if (abs(0 < uA) && abs(uA < 1) && abs(0 < uB) && abs(uB < 1))
    {
        cross = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cross = false;
    }       
    return cross;   
}
```

Comment: Lines or line segments cross?  You mention both.  You can define a line with just 2 points, or you can define the end points of a line segment with 2 points.

Comment: Which two pairs make the coordinates of line segment 1, 2 ?

Comment: Move The second if inside the first else. It won't change the result but it will be clearer. Also, to ease that people helps explain your algorithm.

Comment: Why do you calculate abs of a Boolean?

Comment: The basic idea to calculate this is finding out if each segment intercepts the rectangle defined by the other segment.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/68063).

Comment: Would it help if you had the whole code so that you could understand it in context with the entire program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you said:

```
uA = (x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3) / denom;
uB = (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3) / denom;
```

I think you want:

```
uA = ((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / denom;
uB = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3)) / denom;
```

you said:

```
if (abs(0 < uA) && abs(uA < 1) && abs(0 < uB) && abs(uB < 1))
```

you're taking the absolute value of comparisons, which makes no sense at all.
Did you want:

```
if ((0 < abs(uA)) && (abs(uA) < 1) && (0 < abs(uB)) && abs(uB) < 1))
```

It's bad form, though not necessarily an error, to use integer constants when comparing floats/doubles

Comment: I wondered about those too.  The absolute value of `uA` is never negative; does 0 (or 0.0) count as an intersection?  Would it mean that the segments touch?  Similarly with the comparisons with 1.0?

Comment: I am still not getting any output.  I am just so frustrated.  I am a fairly novice program and this assignment is a bit over my head.

Answer (score 3):

Two line segments *AB* and *CD* cross iff *A* and *B* are on different sides of *CD* and vice-versa. To test whether a point *X* is to the left of an oriented segment *PQ*, use the *ccw* primitive. For some code, see *Line segment intersection* in http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/91primitives/ and some slides at http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/16Geometric.pdf .